# Refresh de pagina com limite

Tags: php, javascript, html

Possivel alguma forma de um script que atualiza a pagina de forma limitada ? exemplo eu mando o script atualizar uma pagina apenas 10 vezes e depois para é possivel ?

Comment: O que tentou, qual a dificuldade encontrada? Precisa dar um pouco mais de detalhes, senão cada leitor pode entender uma coisa diferente do que você quer fazer (e nenhuma das coisas ser o que você busca). Seria mais produtivo [edit] a pergunta e dar um exemplo contextualizando o que pretende, e de tipo de atualização está falando. Aqui tem umas dicas pra elaborar melhor sua pergunta, se não souber por onde começar: [Ask], [Escopo do site](/help/on-topic) e [Help].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esclareça um pouco mais oque precisa, mas sim é possível um exemplo em javascript:

```js
    var vezes = 2;

    var  conta = window.location.href;
    conta = conta.split("conta=");

    if(conta.length > 1){
        var num = conta[1];

        redireciona(num);
    }else{
        redireciona(1);
    }

    function redireciona(num){
        if(num == 'NaN' || num == ''){
            num = 1;
        }
        if(num <= vezes){
            alert('redirecionamento '+num+ ' de '+vezes);
            window.location = "?conta="+(eval(num)+1);
        }

    }
```